# Understanding mpreferred-stack-boundary=number

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm trying to visualize and understand how to utilize mpreferred-stack-boundary(more like build code to exploit it for school). From reading the gcc manual, it states that it aligns the stack according to mpreferred-stack-boundary=number, where number is the exponent to base 2. By default, number=4 so the alignment of the stack is 2^4= 16 bytes. I don't know if it's the caffeine messing with my brain, but all the shell code injections I've seen in class demand that we use mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 when compiling, which would align the stack by 4 bytes. So does that mean I have that the variables placed on the stack try to fill the stack 16 bytes at a time by default? Also, why does shellcode that I place in the buffer work when the boundary when it is set to 2 yet does not work when run it in default mode?

Comment: The size of the whole stack frame will be rounded up to 16 bytes, not each individual local variable. Shellcode would work either way, but code is written for one particular layout so you need to use different shellcode for different layout.

Comment: So you are saying that the stack frame would be rounded up to a multiple of 16 bytes? So if I have a three variables that are 8, 4 and 2 bytes, the stack will try to fit on another 2 bytes from another variable? Or will it pad it?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now. After running it through gdb, I see that it uses an align instruction to ensure that it is 16 bytes. So, my shellcode needed additional NOPs to ensure I fill the buffer. Thank you.

Comment: I just finished writing something about this :
[Hope it's helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43054767/6688314)

Answer (score 2):

The size of the whole stack frame will be rounded up to 16 bytes, not each individual local variable. Shellcode would work either way, but code is written for one particular layout so you need to use different shellcode for different layout. – Jester